# Connect plug to plug for laptop

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Is it OK to `Laptop PSU -> Plug-1 -> Plug-2 -> Wall Socket`?

**Problem**: Plug 1 can accept PSU forks, but its forks are too thick for Wall Socket. Plug 2 fits in Wall Socket, but cannot accept PSU forks. Currently I have `PSU -> Plug-1 -> Extender -> Wall Socket`, but I suspect `Extender`  in causing power issues (graphics errors), so I'd like to rule it out.

**Plugs** (left=1, right=2)

- **1-front**: `B.M.A.`; `Namkem`
- **1-back**: `10A 250V~`; `16A 250V~`; `T-605K2`
- **2-front**: `ADAPDATOR`; `PLUG`; `DO NOT USE IN UK`; `FOR USE ON THE CONTINENT ONLY`; `MAX. LOAD 2200W 250V~`; `1405`; `MAX. LOAD 900W 125V~`
- **2-back**: `9625`; `MADE IN CHINA`; `10A/16A` [all "divided by"] `240V~`
- **PSU**: `Lenovo`; `AC ADAPTER`; `300W 20V`

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just buy the correct adapter?

Comment: …or put the correct plug on the PSU cable, no adaptor required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's literally a bit of brass per terminal, and shouldn't be affecting your GPU. Laptop power supplies are *very* flexible about voltages.

That said

> Plug A can accept PSU forks, but its forks are too thick for Wall Socket. Plug B fits in Wall Socket, but cannot accept PSU forks.

Somehow we can have a standard for 12V cigarette lighters for cars *universally* and yet somehow not for power. Stacking travel adaptors is not a good way to deal with it.

> I suspect Extender in causing power issues (graphics errors), so I'd like to rule it out.

Which is a great reason to go with a *known good* setup.

The 'right' thing to do, safety wise is to get a cable that connects your *national* standard power socket to your power supply. I don't know what country you're in - but here's a [great reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Plugs) - I see *both* type E and F plugs there.  Most laptops are using either a [C5/C6 or a C7/C8 connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C7/C8_coupler). I've seen some laptops using C13s as well. *Get the right cable*. Its relatively cheap and improves safety.

In theory power should pass through just fine but every adaptor you add adds resistance, and you've doubled your risk of an electrical fire, spark or other mishap.

If you *must* get a single, correct adaptor - there's universal ones. If you're going to be using this on the long term, get the correct cable from a trustworthy local retailer.

Comment: "_Somehow we can have a standard for 12V cigarette lighters for cars universally and yet somehow not for power._" Logistics in implementation from cost and building/electrical codes - change receptacle types in a country and there's a lot of cost involved, from manufacturing to every structure, electrical device, etc. I'm in the US, but the UK's plug has always seemed the best since it's not possible for someone to be electrocuted from the plug not being all the way in. Voltage differences also - US starts at ~110V, Europe starts at ~220V _(more efficient)_, resulting in beefier plug terminals

Comment: Or worse, something bridges incorrectly plugged in pins and catches fire. This *was* a humorous reference to stacked travel adaptors - rather than a serious request for a universal power plug... which should be the UK one and 22v obviously :D